# eBay Fulfilment API not returning shipping addresses

Tags: ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I'm trying to retrieve the addresses for unfulfilled orders but for whatever reason since yesterday they've just stopped appearing in the response JSON. The access token is fresh. Everything else is there accept the addresses. For any order.

This is the  production GET request URL I'm using.

```
https://api.ebay.com/sell/fulfillment/v1/order?filter=orderfulfillmentstatus:%7BNOT_STARTED%7CIN_PROGRESS%7D
```

Yesterday I was getting...

```
"fulfillmentStartInstructions": [
     {
         "fulfillmentInstructionsType": "SHIP_TO",
         "minEstimatedDeliveryDate": "2020-05-12T23:00:00.000Z",
         "maxEstimatedDeliveryDate": "2020-05-21T23:00:00.000Z",
         "ebaySupportedFulfillment": false,
         "shippingStep": {
             "shipTo": {
                 "fullName": "####",
                 "contactAddress": {
                     "addressLine1": "####",
                     "addressLine2": "####",
                     "city": "####",
                     "stateOrProvince": "####",
                     "postalCode": "####",
                     "countryCode": "####"
                 },
                 "primaryPhone": {},
                 "email": "####"
             },
             "shippingServiceCode": "UK_StandardShippingFromOutside"
         }
     }
 ]
```

And today...

```
"fulfillmentStartInstructions": [
     {
         "fulfillmentInstructionsType": "SHIP_TO",
         "ebaySupportedFulfillment": false
     }
 ]
```

Missing. Any idea why this might be happening?